# How to sort object by number of properties in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an object

```
{
"William_Hill":{},
"bet365":{},
"royal panda":{"pay":0},
"karamba":{"roller":0,"braned":0,"pay":0},
"betfred":{"braned":0}
}
```

and want to sort it by the nuber of properties, so the result shoul look like this and it must be an object

```
 {
    "William_Hill":{},
    "bet365":{},
    "betfred":{"braned":0},
    "royal panda":{"pay":0},
    "karamba":{"roller":0,"braned":0,"pay":0}
}
```

I have sorted it like this one but the result is an array

```
var keysSorted = Object.keys(resultArray).sort(function(a,b){
    return Object.keys(resultArray[a]).length-Object.keys(resultArray[b]).length;
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no straight forward way to do this :(

Comment: that is the best you get. you can not, actually, sort an object.

Comment: @Rohit416: There is *now*, in ES2015.

Comment: As said, you cant guarantee the order of props in an object.  But since 2015 there is the 'Map' object that might help you..  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: @MattBryson: That's no longer true, as of ES2015.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh well, I should go and take a look then!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Uh, [still not really](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30076219/1048572). If you want something ordered, use a `Map`.

Comment: "*the result should look like this and it must be an object*" - why? What difference does it make?

Comment: @Bergi well as it is not possible, than it can be anything

Comment: @Bergi: As you know, properties **do** now have order, just not in `for-in` or `Object.keys`. Saying otherwise is simply inaccurate.

Comment: @Bergi If you don't use number-like keys, `Symbols` and don't rely on `Object.keys` (and thus on for..in) then the specified order in ES2015 is equivalent to the insertion order.

Comment: @Bergi Why did the ES2015 spec introduce an order anyway? Why this restriction?

Comment: @LUH3417, T.J.Crowder: Yes, that's what the linked question says. However, the spec only defines an order for consistency purposes, not intending for objects being sorted. So even while it might be possible, one still should not do it.

Comment: @Bergi: Indeed, one shouldn't. Which is very different from "not really."

Comment: @Bergi Got it - it's still quite a mess and confusing.

Comment: @SERG: Why do you think you want to put the properties in an order?

Answer (score 1):

Until ES2015, JavaScript object properties *had* no defined order. They do now, but that order isn't respected by `for-in` or `Object.keys`, only by new features like `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`. It's also more complicated than it seems and of *very* limited use.

There's almost never any good reason to try to put an object in a specific order. If you want order, use an array, or in ES2015 use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) (see below).

But that said, in ES2015, with property names like yours, it's possible: The only way to set the order of the properties in an object is to determine the order in which they're *created*, which (for properties that aren't array indexes) is the order they'll be in. So you can do this by getting all the property names, determining the order you want them in, and then creating a *new* object, adding the properties in that order.

**Beware**, though, that certain classes of property names (what we call "array indexes") are sorted differently. None of your property names meets the definition, but (say) `"123"` would.

Here's an example of doing it, if you really want to (I've happily used ES2015's arrow functions, since this only works in ES2015):

```js
// The object
let obj = {
"William_Hill":{},
"bet365":{},
"royal panda":{"pay":0},
"karamba":{"roller":0,"braned":0,"pay":0},
"betfred":{"braned":0}
};

// Get its names, sort them by how may sub-props there are
let names = Object.keys(obj);
names.sort((a, b) => Object.keys(obj[a]).length - Object.keys(obj[b]).length);

// Get the new object
let newObj = names.reduce((acc, name) => {
  acc[name] = obj[name];
  return acc;
}, {});

// Show its property names
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(newObj));
```

Naturally, that can be shorter, I've kept the steps separate for clarity. Similarly, I go back and forth on that use of `reduce`, you could do the last bit like this instead:

```
// Get the new object
var newObj = {};
names.forEach(name => {
  acc[name] = obj[name];
});
```

Here's an example using a `Map` instead, which offers much less complicated ordering of entries (no worries about "array indexes"):

```js
// The object
let obj = {
"William_Hill":{},
"bet365":{},
"royal panda":{"pay":0},
"karamba":{"roller":0,"braned":0,"pay":0},
"betfred":{"braned":0}
};

// Get its names, sort them by how may sub-props there are
let names = Object.keys(obj);
names.sort((a, b) => Object.keys(obj[a]).length - Object.keys(obj[b]).length);

// Get the map
let map = new Map();
names.forEach(name => {
  map.set(name, obj[name]);
});

// Show its property names
console.log(Array.from(map.keys()));
```

Comment: The first thought when i saw this thread was to get an array using `Object.keys` then sort it to _create a new object with the property with desired sort order using the sorted array (but not in ES2015 style)_. Those arrow functions are awesome :)

Comment: @Rohit416: Yup. I love a lot about ES2015, but arrow functions are really, really high on the list. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Dict object in Javascript cannot guarantee the element order.
So maybe you can only use an array to handler the sorted result.

Reference: [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)